# What's going on with the binding of EditTodo in TodoMVC's Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

[The `view Todo.EditTodoView` line of TodoMVC's Ember.js](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html#L23), replicated below, is confusing me:

```
{{#each filteredTodos itemController="todo"}}
    ...
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{view Todos.EditTodoView todoBinding="this"}}
    ...
```

It's not working, which you can see [in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/106/edit). When I doubleclick to edit a todo, the current text disappears and entering doesn't update.

I understand that `"this"` is the TodoController as there was the `itemController` (see more in [this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/83/edit)), but what about the "todo" in `todoBinding`?

---

[The Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/accepting-edits/) has code that [makes it work](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/95/edit), by doing:

```
{{view Todos.EditTodoView valueBinding="title"}}
```

it also says this line binds the `value` property of this `<input>` to the `title` property of this instance of `TodoController`.

---

So what is going on with `todoBinding="this"`?
Is it outdated code?

Comment: after reading better trough your question I've update my answer and added a working jsbin, have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to shed some light to your confusion.

> I understand that "this" is the TodoController as there was the itemController (see more in this jsbin example), but what about the "todo" in todoBinding?

You are correct in assuming that the `this` is set to the defined `itemController` `TodoController`. But, indeed in the [example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html#L23) the line `todoBinding="this"` should read `controllerBinding="this"` since we are trying to access the property `controller` in the `EditTodoView` with `this.get('controller').acceptChanges()`.

So you now have two options, you can change the code in the `EditTodoView` to `this.get('todo').acceptChanges()` or do the change in the template by binding to the `controller` property with `controllerBinding="this"`.

The hole confusion here might be the `todoBinding="this"` where `todo` in `todoBinding` could be called whatever you want, like `fooBinding="this"` as long as you then access the correct name in the `EditTodoView` with `this.get('foo').acceptChanges()`.

> It's not working, which you can see in this jsbin. When I doubleclick to edit a todo, the current text disappears and entering doesn't update.

In your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/93/edit) was also something missing, the binding to the todo's title which I've added, this was the reason of the todo not updating. See here your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxozef/2/edit).

I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response and jsbin. I wonder why [the current version of index.html TodoMVC (updated on May 17, 2013)](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/commits/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html) is functional _without_ `valueBinding="title"`. Thanks

Comment: the current version of the index.html you mentioned is working without `valueBinding="this"` because the same statement is defined in the view instead of the template with this line `valueBinding: 'todo.title'`, so the result is the same. hope it helps :)